# Zend_Db_Select: LEFT JOIN on a subselect

Tags: left-join, zend-db, subquery, zend-db-select

I have a query, that does a `LEFT JOIN` on a subselect. This query is run in a high load environment and performs within the set requirements. The query (highly simplified) looks like:

```
SELECT
  table_A.pKey
, table_A.uKey
, table_A.aaa
, table_B.bbb
, alias_C.ccc
, alias_C.ddd
FROM table_A
INNER JOIN table_B ON table_A.pKey = table_B.pKey
LEFT JOIN (

    SELECT
      table_X.pKey
    , table_X.ccc
    , table_Y.ddd
    FROM table_X
    INNER JOIN table_Y ON table_X.pKey = table_Y.pKey

  ) AS alias_C ON table_A.uKey = alias_C.pKey;
```

<sup>(for various reasons, it is not possible to rewrite the subselect as a (direct) LEFT JOIN).</sup>

Now, I cannot get the `LEFT JOIN on subselect` to work with `Zend_Db_Select`. I've tried everything I could come up with, but it does not work.

**So my question is:**

- Is it not possible to do a query as described above with  `Zend_Db_Select`?
- What syntax do I need to get it to work within Zend Framework?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that it should work like this:

```
$subselect = $db->select->from(array('x' => 'table_X'), array('x.pKey', 'x.ccc', 'y.ddd'), 'dbname')
                        ->join(array('Y' => 'table_Y'), 'x.pkey = y.pkey', array(), 'dbname');

$select = $db->select->from(array('a' => 'table_A'), array(/*needed columns*/), 'dbname')
                     ->join(array('b' => 'table_B'), 'a.pkey = b.pkey', array(), 'dbname')
                     ->joinLeft(array('c' => new Zend_Db_Expr('('.$subselect.')'), 'c.pkey = a.ukey', array())
```

I haven't tried it but I believe it'll work.

Comment: Does that mean it needs to actually execute 2 queries?

Comment: No it will produce one query. Zend_Db_Select is just fluent wrapper to create query. It contains method `toSting()` or `__toString()`. You can try some debugs by calling something like `die($select)` and it will print the query in dialect of db you use.

Comment: great `new Zend_Db_Expr('('.$subselect.')')` is the key, very useful also on Magento !

Comment: thanks - very helpful - just missing the closing bracket in the first array of the last line - it should be: `->joinLeft(array('c' => new Zend_Db_Expr('('.$subselect.')')), 'c.pkey = a.ukey', array())` - can't edit it as SO requires > 6 char change

Answer (score 1):

...
->joinLeft(array('c' => new Zend_Db_Expr('(' . $subselect->assemble() . ')'), 'c.pkey = a.ukey', array())